Error deploying app services on Azure with Python 3.9 and Flask to process Excel files
I have the following environment deployed from VS Code
enter image description here
It was deployed in App Services on Azure using Python 3.9 and Flask to create an application on a B1 plan (Total ACU: 100, 1.75 GB memory, 1 vCPU). The app.py script is as follows:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file
import os
from scripts.misfunciones import process_data

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'uploads')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Guardar los archivos subidos
        data_file = request.files['data_file']
        parametro_file = request.files['parametro_file']
        unidades_file = request.files['unidades_file']
        
        if not os.path.exists(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']):
            os.makedirs(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])

        data_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'uploads', 'DATA.xlsx')
        parametro_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'uploads', '240424RF_Parametro.xlsx')
        unidades_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'uploads', '240306RF_Unidades.xlsx')
        output_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'uploads', 'DATA_FIN.xlsx')

        data_file.save(data_path)
        parametro_file.save(parametro_path)
        unidades_file.save(unidades_path)
        
        process_data(data_path, parametro_path, unidades_path, output_path)
        
        return send_file(output_path, as_attachment=True)

    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

and the script misfunciones.py:
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import re
chars_dict = {
    '\n':'','*':'','°':'','(':'',')':'','+':'',
    '/':'','.':'','_':'',' ':'',',':'','\'':'',
    'á':'a','é':'e','í':'i','ó':'o','ú':'u','-':''
}

def var_lower(df):
    for i in df.columns[1:]:
        df[str(i)] = df[str(i)].str.lower()
        
def remove_pattern(df, pattern):
    for column in df.columns:
        df[column] = df[column].replace(pattern, '', regex=True)
    return df

def process_data(data_path, parametro_path, unidades_path, output_path):
    DATA = pd.read_excel(data_path, engine='openpyxl')
    Parametro = pd.read_excel(parametro_path, engine='openpyxl')
    Unidades = pd.read_excel(unidades_path, engine='openpyxl')

    DATA_CORR = DATA.copy()
    Parametro_CORR = Parametro.copy()
    Unidades_CORR = Unidades.copy()

    DATA_CORR = remove_pattern(DATA_CORR, 'αφ')
    DATA_CORR = remove_pattern(DATA_CORR, 'αδ')
    DATA_CORR = remove_pattern(DATA_CORR, 'φ')

    var_lower(DATA_CORR)
    var_lower(Parametro_CORR)
    var_lower(Unidades_CORR)
    for char, replacement in chars_dict.items():
        escaped_char = re.escape(char)
        DATA_CORR = DATA_CORR.replace(escaped_char, replacement, regex=True)
        Parametro_CORR = Parametro_CORR.replace(escaped_char, replacement, regex=True)
        Unidades_CORR = Unidades_CORR.replace(escaped_char, replacement, regex=True)

    Unificar_Unidad = []
    cantidad = 0
    for i in DATA_CORR['ID-UNIDADES']:
        cantidad += 1
        for j in range(len(Unidades_CORR)):
            for k in Unidades_CORR.columns[1:]:
                if i == Unidades_CORR[k][j]:
                    Unificar_Unidad.append(j + 1)
                    break
            if cantidad == len(Unificar_Unidad):
                break
        if cantidad != len(Unificar_Unidad):
            Unificar_Unidad.append(9999)
    DATA['num_unid'] = Unificar_Unidad

    Unificar_Param = []
    cantidad = 0
    for i in DATA_CORR['ID-PARANETROS']:
        cantidad += 1
        for j in range(len(Parametro_CORR)):
            for k in Parametro_CORR.columns[1:]:
                if i == Parametro_CORR[k][j]:
                    Unificar_Param.append(j + 1)
                    break
            if cantidad == len(Unificar_Param):
                break
        if cantidad != len(Unificar_Param):
            Unificar_Param.append(9999)
    DATA['num_param'] = Unificar_Param

    DATA.to_excel(output_path, index=False)
    return output_path

script index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Subir Archivos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Subir Archivos para Procesar</h1>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="data_file">Archivo DATA:</label>
        <input type="file" name="data_file" id="data_file" required><br><br>
        <label for="parametro_file">Archivo Parametro:</label>
        <input type="file" name="parametro_file" id="parametro_file" required><br><br>
        <label for="unidades_file">Archivo Unidades:</label>
        <input type="file" name="unidades_file" id="unidades_file" required><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Procesar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

However, the application gives an error
enter image description here
I have run it locally and it works correctly. I don't know what is causing the problem, but I think it might be related to the Excel files or some kind of permission. An HTTP 503 error appears in the error list.
I have also tried running it in memory without storing the Excel files, and it worked locally, but not on Azure.
Please, I will appreciate your support to deploy this application correctly on azure.

Yes, Issue could be related to file path of Excel file. I would request you to deploy the excel file with the app files or keep the Excel file in same folder structure of the app file, so that it gets deployed to azure with app file and paths are correct.
To cross check if you application is deployed fine I would suggest to render only the index file in index route ('/'), and perform process of excel file in different route and see if Index file is rendered or not.
Below is my Flask app directory which worked for me.
/Flask_App
--/static
  --/images
    --azure-icon.svg
--/templates
    -- index.html
--app.py
--requirements.txt


index.html:
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Azure - Python Quickstart</title>
</head>
<html>
   <body>
    <div>
        <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/azure-icon.svg')}}" alt="Azure Logo" width="192" height="192"/>
        <h1>Welcome to Azure</h1>  
        <h2>{{message}}</h2>          
      </div>
   </body>
</html>

app.py:
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    message = "Greetings! Wecome to Flask App"
    return render_template('index.html',message=message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

Steps to deploy to WebApp using VS code

Click on Webapp icon in Azure extension and select Deploy to Web App

Select your Project folder

Select your Web App from the list

Click on deploy.

Deployment successful


OUTPUT:
Local :

Azure :


Thanks Vivek, but your answer wasn't able to help me. If you need any more details, please, feel free to ask.

@RayanRenatoFigueroaAsencios you are using two return command for your index function. After first return code wont be executed for 2nd return.

But locally it works. However, update the app.py and index.html code:
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
return render_template('index.html')
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
data_file = request.files['data_file']
parametro_file = request.files['parametro_file']
unidades_file = request.files['unidades_file']

and in local it works, but in azure it doesn't.
Can you try running my code?

In the end it was a version error issue between pandas and numpy libraries :D

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
